# Why am I unable to use Twig conditional on entry.type property?

Tags: templating, conditional

Where **entry.type** is equal to *meetingsEventsOverviewPage*, I would expect the following to return true:

```
{{ entry.type starts with 'meetingsEvents' }}
```

And

```
{{ entry.type in ['meetingsEventsOverviewPage', 'meetingsEventsContactPage'] }}
```

However that doesn't happen.

If I test the string explicitly, it *does* work:

```
{{ 'meetingsEventsOverviewPage' starts with 'meetingsEvents' }}
```

And

```
{{ 'meetingsEventsOverviewPage in ['meetingsEventsOverviewPage', 'meetingsEventsContactPage'] }}
```

Is there some kind of parse order going on here that I need to know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that **entry.type** is actually not a string, but an instance of [EntryTypeModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrytypemodel). This means that **entry.type** is an object containing many different properties, among them the *handle*, which would be the property that you want to test in this case.

In other words, this should work:

```
{{ entry.type.handle starts with 'meetingsEvents' }}
```

Tip: When in doubt about the data your working with, or stuff not working like you'd think, it's often a good idea to *dump*:

```
{{ dump( entry.type ) }}
```

This will output all sorts of useful information about the data, e.g. what it actually is (String, Object etc), all its properties and methods etc.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't tried inspecting it as in other cases it works just fine, presumably because it gets returned as a string, for example, these all work in that they return the handle: {% include '_partials/page_types/' ~ entry.type ignore missing %}, {% if entry.type == 'facilitiesDetailPage' %}. It was only when using 'in' or 'starts with' that I found the issue. Thanks for your help.